# How to call a sub within same sub once?

Tags: vba, excel, subroutine

I want to call a sub routine from the same sub routine based on a condition but exit out of it as soon as it's fulfilled

e.g.

```
Dim p as Long

Sub Main()
  Debug.Print "Start Main"
  p = 1
  call A
  Debug.Print "End Main"
End Sub

Sub A()

  Debug.Print "Start"

  if p = 1 then
     p = 2
     call A
  End if

  Debug.Print "End"

End Sub
```

If I run `Main` I will get following output this is normal since we call A twice so two start and two end

```
Start Main
Start
Start
End
End
End Main
```

But I don't want to return to the `End if` of sub A after it ends that sub first time meaning I want the following output if I call Main

```
Start Main
Start
Start
End
End Main
```

Notice there is only one `End`

Comment: Just `Exit Sub` after `Call A`, or add an `Else` to your `If` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `Exit Sub` where you want A() to end

```vb
Dim p as Long

Sub Main()
  Debug.Print "Start Main"
  p = 1
  call A
  Debug.Print "End Main"
End Sub

Sub A()

  Debug.Print "Start"

  if p = 1 then
     p = 2
     call A
     Exit Sub
  End if

  Debug.Print "End"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

use the else clause

```
Dim p As Long

Sub Main()

    Debug.Print "Start Main"

    p = 1
    Call A

    Debug.Print "End Main"

End Sub

Sub A()

    Debug.Print "Start"

    If p = 1 Then
        p = 2
        Call A
    Else
        Debug.Print "End"
    End If

End Sub
```